# Rails deploy on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

This is my first Heroku deploy and I can not figure out why I am getting those error messages. When I go to my home page I get

```
The page you were looking for doesn't exist.

You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.

If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.

2016-11-16T05:43:25.882366+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-11-16T05:43:25.882326 #4] FATAL -- : [5521b7af-c909-4b91-b923-3a941e622bbd] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
2016-11-16T05:43:25.882420+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-11-16T05:43:25.882382 #4] FATAL -- : [5521b7af-c909-4b91-b923-3a941e622bbd] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
2016-11-16T05:43:25.882493+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-11-16T05:43:25.882436 #4] FATAL -- : [5521b7af-c909-4b91-b923-3a941e622bbd] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
2016-11-16T05:43:25.882555+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-11-16T05:43:25.882490 #4] FATAL -- : [5521b7af-c909-4b91-b923-3a941e622bbd] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
2016-11-16T05:43:25.882578+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-11-16T05:43:25.882534 #4] FATAL -- : [5521b7af-c909-4b91-b923-3a941e622bbd] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
2016-11-16T05:43:25.882624+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-11-16T05:43:25.882580 #4] FATAL -- : [5521b7af-c909-4b91-b923-3a941e622bbd] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
2016-11-16T05:43:25.882670+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-11-16T05:43:25.882627 #4] FATAL -- : [5521b7af-c909-4b91-b923-3a941e622bbd] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/server.rb:578:in `handle_request'
2016-11-16T05:43:25.882722+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-11-16T05:43:25.882673 #4] FATAL -- : [5521b7af-c909-4b91-b923-3a941e622bbd] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/server.rb:415:in `process_client'
2016-11-16T05:43:25.882794+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-11-16T05:43:25.882742 #4] FATAL -- : [5521b7af-c909-4b91-b923-3a941e622bbd] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/server.rb:275:in `block in run'
2016-11-16T05:43:25.882839+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-11-16T05:43:25.882795 #4] FATAL -- : [5521b7af-c909-4b91-b923-3a941e622bbd] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in `call'
2016-11-16T05:43:25.882903+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-11-16T05:43:25.882841 #4] FATAL -- : [5521b7af-c909-4b91-b923-3a941e622bbd] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: You may try restarting the dynos

Comment: 1st of all did you add, `gem "pg"` into gem file ? also, please post yr deploying status to heroku...

Comment: @yurkm3n Deployment was successful

Answer (score 0):

Run `gem install heroku`

Then add heroku to your `Gemfile` and run `Bundle install`

Also, don't forget creating / migrating the database.

```
heroku rake db:create
```

and

```
heroku rake db:migrate
```